# Uploading Multiple Images using HTTP POST

Tags: objective-c, ios7, http-post

I am trying to upload multiple images using HTPP POST method. But somehow its not working. I am uploading 3 images every time but it uploads only 1 image.

Here is the code :

```
- (void)sendImageUploadRequest:(NSMutableArray *)arrImage
{
    if(arrImage)
    {
        NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"upload.php"];
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:ServerURL,strUrl];

        NSString *method =  @"POST";
        NSString *email   = @"xyz@gmail.com";
//        NSString *token   = @"";

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

        NSString *boundary;
            boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];

        // file
        for (int i = 0; i < [arrImagesUpload count]; i++) {

            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([arrImagesUpload objectAtIndex:i], 0.8);
            NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
            [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            NSString *strNameImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test%d.jpg", i];
            NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", strNameImage];
            [body appendData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
            [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
        }

            //  parameter username
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[email dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            //    //  parameter method
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"method\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[method dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            // close form
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
            [request setHTTPBody:body];

        // now lets make the connection to the web
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me solve the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using octet stream and why is the whole body in the loop (not just the image section)?

Comment: Everytime you’re doing `[request setHTTPBody:body];` (which you do on every loop iteration), you’re overwriting the whole post body from the previous iteration, thus only the data from the last iteration remains.

Comment: Well, I recommend putting it back so only the image is in the loop and update that code to your question

Comment: Oh, turns out my analysis was wrong. You do override the post body but you also don’t reset the `body` object so you’re still adding data to that.

Comment: What is your server-side code? If it’s PHP, it should be enough to just use `images[]` for the image name without the explicit number.

Comment: Does it work when you give each image a unique name (without any brackets). Also, are you sure the error isn’t in your server code? Could you post that?

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert yeah check that also but not working

Comment: How is it not working? What’s the exact error?

Comment: @Mac did you get its solution ? i also have same problem right now. so please let me know if you get its solution.

Comment: @AngelAppTech check answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After some efforts Finally i made it worked. Here is the working code:**

```
- (void)sendImageUploadRequest:(NSMutableArray *)arrImage
{
    if(arrImage){
        NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"upload.php"];
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:ServerURL,strUrl];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary]; //initial boundary
        [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableArray *arrImgData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 0; i < [arrImage count];  i++)
        {
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([arrImagesUpload objectAtIndex:i], 0.8);
            [arrImgData insertObject:imageData atIndex:i];
        }

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

        for(int i = 0; i < [arrImage count] ; i++)
        {
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
             NSString *strNameImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.jpg",[self DateTimeWithMilliSeconds],i];
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[%d]\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", i, strNameImage] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:arrImgData[i]]];
            [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }

        //  parameter username
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[appDelegate.credEmail dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; //final boundary

        [request setHTTPBody:body];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[body length]]  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

        // now lets make the connection to the web
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    }    
}
```